# Why symfony form $ builder-> getData () = null in a custom created type?

Tags: forms, propel, symfony-2.3, typeform

I`m use Symfony 2.3 and propel.
I have type form **ClientTyp**e, and the type is declared in it **сlient_profile**

```
 class ClientType extends BaseClientType
    {
        protected $options = array(
            'label' => false,
            'data_class' => 'Artsofte\ClientsBundle\Model\Client',
            'name' => 'client_form'
        );

        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
            $builder
                ->add('сlient_profile', 'client_profile', array(
                    'label' => FALSE
                ))
               ->add(...)
           ;
        }
    }
```

Type form `сlient_profile` create on class `СlientProfileType`

```
class СlientProfileType extends BaseСlientProfileType{

protected $options = array(
    'data_class' => 'Artsofte\DeveloperClientsBundle\Model\СlientProfile',
    'name' => 'Сlient_profile'
);

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
    var_dump($builder->getData());
    $builder
        ->add('name', 'text', array(
            'label' => 'Name client',
            'attr' => array(
                'placeholder' => 'Name client'. $builder->getData()->getName()
        ))
        ->add(..............);
 }
```

`var_dump($builder->getData());` - return is null.
How do I fill in `$builder->getData()` in the form type `client_profile`, or how else can I transfer data from the `client_profile` model to the form type `client_profile`?

Answer (score 0):

in class ClientType add option **clientProfile**. This option add - data model **getData()**

```
class ClientType extends BaseClientType
    {
        protected $options = array(
            'label' => false,
            'data_class' => 'Artsofte\ClientsBundle\Model\Client',
            'name' => 'client_form'
        );

        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
            $builder
                ->add('сlient_profile', 'client_profile', array(
                    'label' => FALSE,
                    'contractorProfile' => $builder->getData(),
                ))
               ->add(...)
           ;
        }
    }
```

but not decided why in class **СlientProfileType** `$builder->getData()` is null.